# Inno Setup: Access to custom control from OnClick event of another control

Tags: event-handling, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have next code for Inno Setup:

```pascal
procedure CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { How to make BrowseButton visible from here? }
end;

procedure CreateTheWizardPage;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  BrowseButton, FormButton: TNewButton;
  CheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
  Memo: TNewMemo;
begin
  Page := PageFromID(wpReady);      
  BrowseButton := TNewButton.Create(Page);
  CheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(Page); 
  CheckBox.OnClick := @CheckBoxClick;
end;
```

I'm wondering how can I access custom controllers on the wizard page from handler procedure for one of them?

Comment: Does this help? http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup.code/msg22922.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the `BrowseButton` variable global and define it before the event handler:

```pascal
var
  BrowseButton: TButton;

procedure CheckBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Now you can use the BrowseButton here }
end;

procedure CreateTheWizardPage;
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
  FormButton: TNewButton;
  CheckBox: TNewCheckBox;
  Memo: TNewMemo;
begin
  Page := PageFromID(wpReady);      
  BrowseButton := TNewButton.Create(Page);
  CheckBox := TNewCheckBox.Create(Page); 
  CheckBox.OnClick := @CheckBoxClick;
end;
```

---

Related question: [Reading values from custom Inno Setup wizard pages without using global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38792593/850848)