# Inno Setup custom wizard pages ("installation checklist") change text at runtime

Tags: inno-setup

I made a custom wizard page, and I want it to show a sort of installation checklist at the end of the install, showing what installed successfully or not.

Something like

```
Crucial Step......................SUCCESS
Optional Step.....................FAILURE
```

So I have this code in my `initializeWizard()`

```
Page := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'Installation Checklist', 'Status of all installation components');

RichEditViewer := TRichEditViewer.Create(Page);
RichEditViewer.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
RichEditViewer.Height := Page.SurfaceHeight;
RichEditViewer.Parent := Page.Surface;
RichEditViewer.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
RichEditViewer.UseRichEdit := True;
RichEditViewer.RTFText := ''// I want this attribute to be set in CurStepChanged()
```

Is there a way to add or edit `RichEditViewer.RTFText` at a later point in time? `Page` is a global variable but trying to access any attributes gives me an error. I'd like to do edit the text after wpInstalling, so I can tell whether or not install steps were successful.

Comment: *"trying to access any attributes gives me an error"* - What attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of this method, but you Can set your RichEditViewer as a global, and then editing it at any point, in any function, is trivial.

```
var
  RichEditViewer: TRichEditViewer;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'Installation Checklist', '');

  RichEditViewer := TRichEditViewer.Create(Page);
  RichEditViewer.Width := Page.SurfaceWidth;
  RichEditViewer.Height := Page.SurfaceHeight;
  RichEditViewer.Parent := Page.Surface;
  RichEditViewer.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
  RichEditViewer.UseRichEdit := True;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep=ssPostInstall then RichEditViewer.RTFText := 'STUFF';
end;
```

Worthwhile to note, the page itself doesn't even need to be global.

Comment: I do not understand what problem you have with this method. It's by far the best way. The only other is to lookup a child of the `Page` using `FindComponent` method or by iterating the `Controls` list.

Comment: Just a personal aversion to global variables.

Comment: We discussed this already: [Reading values from custom wizard pages without using global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38792593/850848).

Comment: Again, in Inno Setup you implement application hooks. Its API does not offer you any other way, except for global variables, for preserving a state.